Trigger a PDF generation fail for testing without touching code
As SF QA, is there a way to create test steps to trigger a PDF generation fail? Once I complete an onboarding flow, a contract form generates. I need to test that once the form generation does not happen, that an error message displays.
I attempted to block the request URL through inspect>network, but no luck there. Not sure I even chose the correct request to block.
Any advice for a manual QA tester?

From your question it's unclear to me what actually generates the PDF. But in terms of displaying a specific error message, I'm assuming the PDF gets written to the database as a ContentVersion and there is a page/component that then queries for it. If you can delete the PDF when that code runs and fails to find it, that is where you'd want to place the error message.
